# C++ multi-threading mutex lock "reset"

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I use a `std::mutex` in my multi-threaded application for accessing the same resource by multiple threads. This works fine. But at some point of my code, I have to terminate the threads using `TerminateThread(...)`. When I begin the thread again (using `_beginthreadex`), I get an exception if one of the threads was at the mutex lock when it was terminated:

> Concurrency::improper_lock bei Speicherort 0x03B4F3D0.

This is thrown in rtlocks.cpp, line 1184 (in `bool critical_section::_Acquire_lock`):

```
LockQueueNode * pPrevious = reinterpret_cast<LockQueueNode *>(InterlockedExchangePointer(&_M_pTail, pNewNode));
```

I guess, if I could "reset" the mutex, I would get an exception, right? How can I do this?

(I use `<process.h>`)

**edit**

I tried the following:

```
std::mutex dataStorage_lock;
mutexHandler[0] = &dataStorage_lock; //storing all mutexs in an array

//when trying to delete:
delete mutexHandler[0];
```

But I get:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Comment: refactor the code so that you don't have to terminate threads. There's nothing more to discuss.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why `TerminateThread()` is unsafe. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150814-00/?p=91811  That article has the bonus poem by Larry Osterman: "How many times does it have to be said: Never call TerminateThread"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is pseudocode, but you ought to get the idea:

wrong:

```
function thread_proc():
  for_ever:
    do_things

function stop_my_thread():
  TerminateThread(...)
```

right:

```
function thread_proc():
  while(not terminate_signal):
    do_things

function stop_my_thread():
  terminate_signal.set();  // signals the thread to terminate
  thread.join();           // waits for the thread to terminate
```

Comment: So as signal, I could use a normal boolean, e.g. `bool doExit`. When I want to make the thread terminating, I set (in my main function) `doExit=true`. But I would need another `mutex`for `doExit`, because I could get an error when I set it to true while it is retrieved in the if condition in the thread, right?

Comment: @black you should use either an atomic (see `std::atomic`) or a condition_variable (`std::condition_variable`). In the windows world you could use an `Event` if you don't mind being non-standard. Don't just use an ordinary variable. The c++ standard does not offer any guarantees that a change made in one thread will be seen in another (this includes volatile variables - they are not for threading, they're for I/O).

Answer (score 2):

You either need to destroy the mutex and create a brand new one, or you can modify your code such that when waiting on the mutex the thread can be interrupted (rather than terminated).  For some ideas on interruption, see here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.interruption

Comment: I do not use boost; I include process.h. Any similar solution?

Comment: To your first solution (destroying the mutex): Is there something that is like `myMutex=NULL`?

Comment: @black: If you have `mutex* m = new mutex();` then you can later do `delete m` and create it again from scratch.

Comment: @black: You screwed up and called `delete` on the address of an automatic (stack) variable.  You cannot do that!  You need to call `new` to create it and `delete` to destroy it.